# Using SpEL to copy references of a beans is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spelevaluationexception, beancreationexception

I have been experimenting around with Spring. I wish to copy a bean's value and reference properties for another bean by making use of SpEL.

Consider this bean:

```
<bean id="kenny" class="com.springinaction.springidol.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="#{'Jingle Bells'}" /> 
    <property name="instrument" ref="piano" /> 
</bean>
```

I wish to copy its values into another bean, as shown below:

```
<bean id="carl" class="com.springinaction.springidol.Instrumentalist"> 
    <property name="song" value="#{kenny.song}" /> 
    <property name="instrument" ref="#{kenny.instrument}" /> <-- I GET EXCEPTION OVER HERE

</bean>
```

However, I get an exception for the second prpoperty as it does not manage to copy kenny's intrument. The song is copied correctly without any exception being thrown

I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'carl' defined in class path resource
>   [Beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '#{kenny.instrument}'
>   while setting bean property 'instrument'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression
>   parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1008E:(pos 6): Field or property 'instrument' cannot be found on
>   object of type 'com.springinaction.springidol.Instrumentalist'

**Any idea how I can copy the instrument and set it for the bean with id "carl" please?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ref` is a reference to another bean; in your case you want to use the value of the `instrumemt` property of the `kenny` bean.

You should use

```
 <property name="instrument" value="#{kenny.instrument}" />
```

This assumes there is a `getInstrument()` method on `Instrumentalist`.

Comment: Thanks it works. The only reason why I added reference because the instrument kenny is referring to is a bean too.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the source of the kenny property was a bean; at the point of resolving, that association is lost - you can use `ref="piano"` or `value="#{kenny.instrument}`.